# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{Si}(n \pi)}{n}=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-\ln{\pi}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

Prove $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{Si}(n \pi)}{n}=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(1-\ln{\pi}\right)$$
Where Si(x) is the sine integral function.  This is where I'm stuck on the original question $$\int\limits_{\pi }^{+\infty }{\frac{\sin x}{x}dx}+\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{2\pi }^{+\infty }{\frac{\sin x}{x}dx}+\frac{1}{3}\int\limits_{3\pi }^{+\infty }{\frac{\sin x}{x}dx+...}$$
I am really not sure what to do for the sum!  Maybe there is a better approach than evaluating the sum I have here.  Any help please.